# pandas - create key value pair from grouped by data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with three columns, I would like to create a dictionary after applying groupby function on first and second column.I can do this by for loops, but is there any pandas way of doing it?

DataFrame:

```
Col X    Col Y    Sum
 A         a       3
 A         b       2
 A         c       1
 B         p       5
 B         q       6
 B         r       7
```

After grouping by on Col X and Col Y : df.groupby(['Col X','Col Y']).sum()

```
                  Sum
Col X    Col Y    
 A         a       3
           b       2
           c       1
 B         p       5
           q       6
           r       7
```

Dictionary I want to create

```
{A:{'a':3,'b':2,'c':1}, B:{'p':5,'q':6,'r':7}}
```

Comment: You don't need `groupby()` - `df.set_index(['Col X', 'Col Y'])` should work.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension while iterating via a `groupby` object

```
{name: dict(zip(g['Col Y'], g['Sum'])) for name, g in df.groupby('Col X')}

{'A': {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, 'B': {'p': 5, 'q': 6, 'r': 7}}
```

If you insisted on using `to_dict` somewhere, you could do something like this:

```
s = df.set_index(['Col X', 'Col Y']).Sum
{k: s.xs(k).to_dict() for k in s.index.levels[0]}

{'A': {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, 'B': {'p': 5, 'q': 6, 'r': 7}}
```

---

Keep in mind, that the `to_dict` method is just using some comprehension under the hood.  If you have a special use case that requires something more than what the `orient` options provide for... there is no shame in constructing your own comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was wondering, if we could do some thing like df.to_dict()

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `MultiIndex` series:

```
>>> s = df.set_index(['ColX', 'ColY'])['Sum']
>>> {k: v.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_dict() for k, v in s.groupby(level=0)}
{'A': {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}, 'B': {'p': 5, 'q': 6, 'r': 7}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#A to_dict() solution

d = df.groupby(['Col X','Col Y']).sum().reset_index().pivot(columns='Col X',values='Sum').to_dict()

Out[70]: 
{'A': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'B': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 5.0, 4: 6.0, 5: 7.0}}

#if you need to get rid of the nans:
{k1:{k2:v2 for k2,v2 in v1.items() if pd.notnull(v2)} for k1,v1 in d.items()}
Out[73]: {'A': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0}, 'B': {3: 5.0, 4: 6.0, 5: 7.0}}
```